# Passo value via props para um input mas o onchange não altera o value

Tags: react

Tem um component que retorna um input e passo os dados(name, value, etc) para ele via props, o valor de value é um state e o onchange que passo também via props não está manipulando e alterando o value do input

```
  let [userName, setUserName ] = useState('')

const verifyLogin = (e) => {
    setUserName(e.target.value)
    e.preventDefault();
  }

function Data(props) {
    return (
        <div className={styles.data}>
            <input type={props.type} value={props.text} name={props.name} id={props.id} onChange={props.onChange}/>
        </div>
    ) 
  }

return(
  <Data type='text' name='name' text={userName} id='username' htmlFor='name' dataName='Username' 
  onChange={verifyLogin}/>
)
```

O value e o state deviam alterar mas não acontece

Answer (score -2):

O problema pode ser causado porque o componente Data está recebendo o valor de props.text como uma propriedade de somente leitura, o que significa que o valor não pode ser alterado pelo componente filho.

Para corrigir isso, você pode passar o valor do estado como uma propriedade defaultValue no lugar de value:

```
function Data(props) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.data}>
      <input
        type={props.type}
        defaultValue={props.text}
        name={props.name}
        id={props.id}
        onChange={props.onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Dessa forma, o componente Data pode alterar o valor do input, e o gerenciamento de estado pode ser realizado pelo componente pai usando a função verifyLogin.

espero ter ajudado